# Giving lettes an individual node

Tags: texture-baking

First of all. Im a total noob at blender. I only have a few days of training.

I am working on a logo for an animation. Im trying to bake the scene, but my text is too long for only one bake map (or texture or what ever) So I have seperated each letter so they can be baked one at a time. But they all still share the same node ?

How do I give them one each ?

Comment: Do you mean material by 'texture'?

Comment: Kind off. All the letters need to be the same meterial, but when I need to bake it and add the texture from the baking, they need one each that is not the same.

Comment: So after baking you have the same amount of materials as the amount of letters right? And now these letters share the same material, but you want each letter to have their own baked material? :)

Comment: yes. I bake the shadows for each letter because they cant all be in one bake. S And the shadow of one letter is not the same as the next, so they need their own bake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to Material Tab, then click the **+** button next to your material, now press the 'Brows Material to be Linked' button and finally press the **2** button next to the material name. Now you have to go to edit mode and click the Assign button at the bottom of the materials list while the letter you want to give the particular material is selected.
*By adjusting the new material you will now change the previous*
Just see the Gif.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for the GIF quality, first time I'm doing it, hope you understand.

Comment: Why is the 2-button necessary? :)

Comment: to make sure that when you change this new material the changes don't apply to the default material

Comment: And then I apply a baked texture to each material ?

Comment: well, pretty much yes

Comment: and by "pretty much" you mean ?

Comment: I mean yes, *sorry for my structure*

Comment: it works, but it did not fix the problem :S

I get this when I try to bake the first letter. The letter is all white so it does not make sense. http://imgur.com/Dcvs94T

I have baked everything else exept the letter. I tried to render to see how much faster it was now, but the letters is all dark, like if the light wasnt there. is that because everything else is baked ?