# How do i add material/textures to only one face of an object?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I just got Blender and I don't know how to add textures to only one side. I've tried finding an answer but i can't. It adds the texture to all sides of the object.[image]

I just want the blue on one side of the square. BTW i don't know where anything is in blender so if you have an answer please include pictures.

Comment: If you want to add a different material to a different face of your cube see how to do it here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: See this answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36023/15366

Comment: How do i select a side of the object?

Comment: @Funshine  your last comment had a question which is probably best answered in a video tutorial series.  Here is one example of a series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw

Answer (score 16):

In *Edit Mode* select a face (using a *face selection* [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>*-->Face*]) you want a texture to be projected on. Then press <kbd>U</kbd>*-->Unwrap*. In *Uv Editor* open your image texture.
[image]

Add a new material to your face (using a ***+*** button) and press the ***Assign*** button.
[image]

Then go to the ***Texture*** header. Add a new texture and change its type to ***Image or Movie***. Open an image and change its coordinates (in a *Mapping* panel) to ***UV***.
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Followed these instructions but the 3d view doesn't show my texture. Blender 2.79b

Comment: @ether_joe Have you tried to change **Viewport Shading** to **Texture Mode** (It's Solid by default)?

Comment: Eventually I realized I needed to hit U -> unwrap *after* assigning the materials. Now working.

Comment: I was banging my head over this for a while. Thanks!

Comment: I am struggling to follow these instruction on blender v2.91. after creating a material, how do I add a texture to it? I do not find the texture header.

Comment: This desperately needs updating for the newer blender versions after everything got moved around in 2.8/9

Comment: @Kai After adding the material click on the dot next to "Base Color" and choose "Image Texture". Then add your image.

Comment: What a huge overkill to do this simple thing :-(. I'm missing a way, which is common to all other modelling programs. Just select a face, choose a texture and choose a scale or rotation.