# Adding a texture to one face in Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

How do you add a texture to one face of a cube in 2.8?

I get stuck on the instructions below when it tells you to "Go to the texture header" in the materials context. In my version there is no texture header in the materials context.

[How do i add material/textures to only one face of an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36401/how-do-i-add-material-textures-to-only-one-face-of-an-object)

Comment: select the face, go in the Properties editor > Material tab, create a new slot with the + button, give it a new material, click on the Assign button

Comment: That assigns a material to the face but I want that face to have a texture.

Comment: Assign the texture to the material. You can't just add a texture without using a material.

Comment: That was where I was originally stuck!

Answer (score 2):

OK I figured this out.

After adding a material slot and clicking new:

Click the small dot next to 'base material' and select 'Image Texture' that then allows you to load a texture for the material and can be assigned to the face.

Comment: Or do it in the Shader editor which makes thingd more understandable in my opinion

Comment: why don't you select your answer as accepted (click the check mark next the answer) so everyone knows you found an answer?

Comment: Doing it in the shader editor was where I ended up after about 3 hours of messing about!

Comment: I can't mark my own answer as correct until 24 hours have passed.