# How to make these faces just one material?

Tags: materials

I'm making this dinosaur, and I'm making certain parts certain materials. For some reason, some faces do this. They are set to be the tan material, but show some red. I'm pretty new to this so it may be a simple answer, maybe not. If you need anymore information, just ask. This is also my first time using this site.[image: The faces in the tan area that have some red in them are the issue.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36401/how-do-i-add-material-textures-to-only-one-face-of-an-object