# Quality of rendering an Image Texture on a surface

Tags: image

Blender version **2.83**.

I learnt putting an image on a surface with [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36401/how-do-i-add-material-textures-to-only-one-face-of-an-object).
All is working well. But, the output image isn't as 'high quality' as expected.

First, I create a 2D image in inkscape, 512x512.

Then, putting it on a surface, as below:
[image]

Finally, **Render** -> **Image** -> **Save As**

Comparing side by side:
[image]

The left is the original 2D image, the right is the rendered image in Blender.

I can observe that, the word 'abc', originally white color, becomes a little 'grey' or 'dull'.
(It just doesn't look as bright and vivid as the origin, did i miss some configuration?)

**P.S.:**
Am I supposed to build the entire thing in blender instead of loading image....

Comment: It's the default color management, it makes everything look gray. Do [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164679/88681).

Comment: If it's not a problem of color management, icrease the light power, or use an Emission node instead of a Diffuse node (but in that case your face won't be affected by lights and environment)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @scurest, the color management is the reason.
The answer in that link exactly explained it:
`Color Management -> View Transform -> Standard` (instead of `Filmic`)

Thanks!