# Aplying material to individual faces of multiple objects

Tags: materials, node-editor, faces

OK, I am a newish user working with Blender 2.75 since August 1.

I have my first complex project modeled, time for some color.
Several objects in my model require different materials on different parts of the object. So, I picked out faces on an object and used the Node Editor to create a new material for them.  I then picked the other faces and created another new material for them. So far so good, that object now has the correct materials.
Now switching to another object I go into edit mode and pick out several faces. But when I go to materials and try to assign one of the materials to the faces it gets applied to the entire object. I try picking other faces and try applying a different material. Again the entire object is changed to that material.

Am I missing something obvious? Do I need to recreate the same NEW material for each object in order to apply it to selected faces?

Comment: Please see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/giving-lettes-an-individual-node

Comment: And this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh